# jQuery masonry resize event with api

Tags: jquery, masonry

Can this resize event be used with api?

I have tried this but it doesnt not work:

```
grid.masonry('resize', false);
```

then later when I need it again:

```
grid.masonry('resize', true);
```

https://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#resize

I want to disable resize in certain scenarios but be able to enable it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resize` is an option, not a method, so you should do it like this:

```
grid.masonry({ resize: false });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: But isnt this init method? so you have to init grid to call it every time?

Comment: @Toniq `.masonry()` is the initializer, but also serves to pass options and execute methods in the instance. It will also execute `.layout()` if called without any arguments (this will redraw the grid). So yes, you can use the `.masonry()` function again after the initialization.